# How to attach file using actionFunction

Tags: actionfunction, regular-expressions, heap

Could you help me please? I want to implement attaching files to Cases in SalesForce.

There is recomanded way which using apex:inputFile element, but I can’t use it, because on page I have to use more rerendering scopes.

So I decided to implement it via standard html input and action function with parameters (where content of file is passed in parameter to apex class).

Visualforce:

```
<apex:form id="techForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<apex:actionFunction name="fillAttachment" action="{!formController.FillAttachment}" reRender="attachmentsBlock">
<apex:param assignTo="{!formController.handleFileContent}" name="handleFileContent" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_extension(filename) {
var files = document.getElementById('attachment').files;                     
var file = files[0];
fillAttachment(file);
}
</script> 
<input type="file" accept=".gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .tif, .tiff, .png, .pdf" onChange="check_extension(this.value)" class="hidden" value="" filename="attachment" id="attachment" />
</form>
```

Apex Class:

```
public class ContactUsController {
    public  List<Attachment> attachments { get; set; }
    public String handleFileContent { get; set; }  
public void FillAttachment() {
if(this.handleFileContent != null && this.handleFileContent.length() > 0) {
Attachment toAttach = new Attachment(body = Blob.valueOf(this.handleFileContent));
this.attachments.add(toAttach);
}
}
}
```

**The problem of this approach is that in this way, i got „Regex too complicated“ error.**
S

- o, I tried to check heap size
  (http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/08/16/managing-the-heap-in-salesforce-com/),but it is no problem.
- I also tryied to use Transcient method, but it  does not work
- Finnaly I tried to use future method, but it is static, so it is not
  possible for me to use it.

I suggest that problem is that I exceed limit of view stat

Can you help me?

To Sum Up. ***Is there any way, how to send file from visualforce page using javascript and actionfunction to apex class? I can not use apex:imputFile because I have to use more rerender scopes on that page. I hope that there will be some workaround.***

(I thinking about iframe page using apex:imputFile embedded to my page which handle uploading attachments and then via timpestamp-identifiers map it to relevant Case. But I think that it is "weird" way to upload files.)

Thank you for your answer.

Martin

Comment: Check this link, I think it will work for you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33033/html-equivalent-of-apexinputfile

Comment: Tank you for answer, there is solution via connection.js, but I can not use connection.js, because it is forbidden for Site guest user.

Comment: You can try Javascript Remotin. Please check this link https://forceadventure.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/uploading-attachments-to-salesforce-using-javascript-remoting/